# Symfony2 entity manager file

Tags: symfony

I am developing a application using Symfony 2 and I would like to know where can I find the entity manager configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Answer (score 0):

In [dbal.xml](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/dbal.xml#L54) file of   `DoctrineBundle`.